# Unable to assign self generated _id as reference in other collection in mongo shell

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I am trying to create two collections in mongoDB. The collections are named `roles` and `users`. I read that `_id` is self-generated id returned by MongoDB on each document insertion. But if we try to insert into the document with the `_id` key then there is no new Object ID generated.

So I created a collection `roles` like below-

`db.roles.insertOne({"_id" : 101, "name": "admin", "type":1})`

`db.roles.insertOne({"_id" : 102, "name": "guest", "type":1})`

Now, I tried to use these _ids of roles collection in my `users` table like below -

`db.users.insertOne({"username": "test", "password": "test", role: ObjectId(101)})`

But it throws me an error saying -
 `invalid object id: length :`
However, if I try to insert a Mongo generated ID, something like  `ObjectId("600045071dbbafd62cdd6045")`, it is able to insert the document.
Can anyone please tell me, what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you need to insert the role same way like the _id, role:101

Comment: I want to add a reference here. Would merely adding role like role: 101 count as a reference?

Comment: Yes as far as the _id:101 is the corresponding referencing roles document...